# Regular expression with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, escaping

-Hi
I'm new with Jquery.

I have to recognize this `[H]` at JQuery.

At the moment, i recognize letters.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":button#boton").click(function () {
        if ($(":text#texto").attr("value").match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            alert("Bien");
        } else {
            alert("Esto no son letras");
        }
    });
});
```

How can I scape this symbol `[`?. With `\`?

Thank you in advance.
KR. Blanca

Comment: What is the output you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can `escape` special characters in [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) it by preceding it by `\`:

```
if ($(":text#texto").attr("value").match(/^[a-zA-Z\[H\]]+$/)) {
//                                                ^^^^^
```

To recognize `[H]` using `regex`:

```
if ($(":text#texto").attr("value").match(/\[H\]+/g)) {
//                                        ^^^^^  ^
```

> A backslash that precedes a special character indicates that the next character is not special and should be interpreted literally. For example, the pattern /a*/ relies on the special character '*' to match 0 or more a's. By contrast, the pattern /a*/ removes the specialness of the '*' to enable matches with strings like 'a*'.